# What is the correct parameter list for TDownloadURL.AfterDownload

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

```
{ Download the license file with expiration date }
  iDownloadURL := TDownloadURL.Create(nil);
  try
    iBaseURL := DomainName1.Text;
    iDownloadURL.FileName := ATempFilesFolder + UserName1.Text + 'lcn';
    iDownloadURL.url := iBaseURL;
    iDownloadURL.OnDownloadProgress := URL_OnDownloadProgress;
    iDownloadURL.AfterDownload := AfterDownloadLicense; {License is validated here }
    iDownloadURL.ExecuteTarget(nil);
  finally
    { If a connection fails then a dialog will appear that shows an error.
    If running in the ide then an exception box will appear, Press the continue
    button... then the message will be shown }
    iDownloadURL.Free;
    StatusBar1.SimpleText := 'Failed validation connection...';
    Form1.StatusBar1.SimpleText := 'Failed validation connection...';
  end;

procedure TFormDomainSettings.AfterDownloadLicense;
begin
  if not FileExists(ATempFilesFolder + UserName1.Text + 'lcn') then
  begin
    TaskMessageDlg('Error Downloading License File',
      'The license file could not be downloaded.', mtWarning, [mbOk], 0);
  end
  else
  begin
    ValidateLicense;
  end;
end;
```

How do you assign the iDownloadURL.AfterDownload := AfterDownloadLicense; TNotifyEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have looked that up in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent), or even using the IDE editor to find the `TNotifyEvent` declaration in `System.Classes.pas`:

```
TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
```

With that said, `AfterDownloadLicense()` needs to look like this:

```
procedure TFormDomainSettings.AfterDownloadLicense(Sender: TObject);
```

Comment: Sorry... I thought I tried that earlier but it would not compile.